# Remover uma ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tem algum jeito de remover uma imagem em um *ImageView* ou deixar ela vazia via código?

Por exemplo: Eu "seto"

```
img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
```

Tem como remove-lá via código?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim

```
img1.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Outra possível solução seria

```
img1.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: Valeu, consegui aqui!!!